# Forwarding slash in Wordpress URL

Tags: wordpress, url

I am moving my site from Drupal to Wordpress.

In Drupal, I can easily give an alias to URL and this alias could be anything., ie: www.example.com/abc/xyz/hello.html

But in Wordpress, it appears that I cannot do that with WP out of the box.

Any hint on how to do the same with Wordpress? I need to keep URL consistence.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I just found out this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/ and used it to add caracters like slashes and points, to the urls of a website i am moving to WordPress, so far it's working.
Hope it will help !

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in Settings -> Permalinks, but I think you want more than that.

Take a look at the feature list for the [redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/). This allows you to setup redirects to other pages or do [pass through](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/) redirections. If this isn't what you are looking for then I think there are a couple other plugins that may accomplish what you want. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Redirection is the last solution we will use. But if all other means fail, we will try this. Settings -> Permalinks is not enough. Basically, I want to name URL freely, no rules or patterns. I can do that in Drupal but Wordpress does not allow me to do that.

Comment: As I mentioned take a look at the 'pass-through' option. I think this does exactly what you want. You get a 200 response and not a 301. I added a link to their full documentation in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default urls in the Settings -> Permalinks.  You should also have the option to change the permalink when you add or edit a post.  There are also plugins available for permalinks (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-permalinks/)

Comment: Thanks. But that plugin is compatible up to: 2.9.2 and we are using latest version. I will give it a try anyway. Settings -> Permalinks is not enough. Basically, I want to name URL freely, no rules or patterns. I can do that in Drupal but Wordpress does not allow me to do that.

Comment: Try setting your Permalink to Custom Structure = /%postname%/   I did this to my blog (WordPress 3.2.1) and was able to create urls that were in the form of www.mydomain.com/whatever_I_wanted/

Comment: BTW, the plugin was an example of a plugin that is out there.  I am using the out of the box WordPress 3.2.1.  Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Travis: I tried that (/%postname%/) but it does not work well. eg: I want a URL name about/history.html. Both the forwarding slash ("/") and the dot were gone (dot was replace with "-")