# Prevent WordPress from removing "/" in URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say I publish a page in WordPress and it generates a url like this.

**`mydomain.com/pagestructure`**

I need to have this structure

**`mydomain.com/page/structure`**

I figured several ways of doing that.

1. Edit url from the page edit screen
2. Edit permalink structure and use Custom structure there
3. Edit .htaccess

I can't use the second method because I need this structure only for a single, particular page. Not for all pages.

I can't use third method as it is a bit difficult for me. Sorry for that.

The first method is I want to use as it is the most simpler one. But I am not able to use it because WP does not allow putting **"/"** at desired places. It re-writes them. If by somehow I prevent the re-writing of **"/"**, maybe via adding a rewrite rule via **"add_rewrite_rule"**, it might solve the problem. Any help?

Comment: What's the problem if you don't have the trailing slash?

Comment: Its just a requirement.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082940/forwarding-slash-in-wordpress-url) seemed to get solved by using a plugin, maybe that will fit your needs, too.

On the other hand: Why do you want to have that specific structure? WordPress would create such a structure automatically, if you use the parent page functionality.

Comment: Yes I solved it already with parent page creation. I just wanted to improve my knowledge database. I mean I wanted to know if it is even possible.